# Ler variável na memoria(BaseAddress + OffSet)

Tags: c++, processo

Estou tentando ler uma variável dentro de outro processo, no caso do jogo "Paciência Spider". Até agora deu tudo certo, porém quando eu fecho o jogo e abro de novo não funciona mais.

Eu sei que quando fecha e abre o local da variável na memoria muda e precisa fazer um calculo para saber o endereço(Adress = BaseAddress + OffSet). Eu só consigo esse Address pelo ArtMoney, mas nao sei como achar o base nem o offset. Alguem tem como me ajudar?

Meu codigo:

```
int main()
{
std::wstring processName = L"SpiderSolitaire.exe";

DWORD pid = FindProcessId(processName);
DWORD*address = (DWORD*)0x000000525570;
DWORD value;

if (pid == 0) {
    std::wcout << "nao achou " << processName.c_str() << std::endl;
}
else {
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid); 

    if (!phandle) 
    {
        cout << "nao achou handle \n";
        cin.get();
    }

        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, address, &value, sizeof(value), 0);
        cout << value << "\n"; //mostra o valor
        Sleep(1000); 

}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
{
PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 0;

Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
{
    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
    return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
}

while (Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
{
    if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
    {
        CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }
}

CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
return 0;
```

}